# PHP: Seperate a number to 10er array with a minimum and maximum value

Tags: php, arrays, max, php-7, min

I do not know how to form this the right way so here is the concept.

I have for example the **93.5** and **35** as numbers.

What i would like to do is to get from the minimum value the previous 10er number, in this case the 30 and get from the maximum value the next 10er number which in this case is 100.

The next step is to get an array from each 10er number between those two numbers. It would look like this:

```
array(8 items)
   0 => 30 
   1 => 40 
   2 => 50 
   3 => 60 
   4 => 70 
   5 => 80 
   6 => 90 
   7 => 100
```

So the question is, how do i achieve that with PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some coding i have found the solution.

First step: Get the minimum and maximum numbers and set them to the previous and next 10er number:

```
$minSize = floor(35 / 10) * 10; /* Gives back 30 */
$maxSize = ceil( 93.5 / 10) * 10; /* Gives back 100*/
```

Now get the number from the `$maxSize` didvided by **10**.

```
$devidedNumber = $maxSize / 10; /* Gives back 10 */
```

After that, a `for` iteration is to be created using the `$devidedNumber` in order to decide how many times this iteration should run.

```
$sizedArray = array();

for ($i = $minSize/10; $i <= $devidedNumber; $i++)
{
   $sizedArray[] = $i * 10;
}
```

The `$i` starts from **3** because we need the value that starts from **30** to the target value.

And the result:

```
array(8 items)
   0 => 30 
   1 => 40 
   2 => 50 
   3 => 60 
   4 => 70 
   5 => 80 
   6 => 90 
   7 => 100
```

**EDIT:**

After @Nigel Ren answer, another way to do it is the following. After rounding the numbers, the `for` iteration could look like this:

```
 for ($i = $minSize; $i <= $maxSize; $i+=10)
 {
    $sizedArray[] = $l;
 }
```

In this case, the code is simplified by removing the line

```
 $devidedNumber = $maxSize / 10; /* Gives back 10 */
```

and get directly the between values from the rounded.

Thanks for the nice suggestion

Comment: You could simplify your for loop by using the increment as 10 - `for ($i = $minSize; $i <= $maxSize; $i+=10) {  $sizedArray[] = $i; }`

Comment: let me edit the solution adding your method as well